# Why Recylerview does not showing data properly?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

After clicking on the Add button it only show the First item. But when I touch the edit text field the remaining items are shown and gone.

Here is the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.mysecondapp.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText editText;
    Button add,ins;
    ArrayList<item> list;
    Adapter adpter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ins= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        list=new ArrayList<item>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adpter =new Adapter(new ArrayList<item>());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adpter);


        ins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String str=editText.getText().toString();
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager= (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
                editText.setText(" ");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Added to list",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                item i=new item(str);
                list.add(i);
            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adpter.adplist=list;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Adding to Recycler View",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });



       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the Adapter

```
package com.example.mysecondapp.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyHolder> {
    ArrayList<item> adplist;

    public ArrayList<item> getAdplist() {
        return adplist;
    }

    public void setAdplist(ArrayList<item> adplist) {
        this.adplist = adplist;
    }

    public Adapter(ArrayList<item>list) {
        adplist=new ArrayList<item>();

        adplist=list;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new MyHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        item i=adplist.get(position);
        holder.tv.setText(i.getStr());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adplist.size();
    }

    public class MyHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tv;
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is The item

```
package com.example.mysecondapp.myapplication;

public class item {
    String str;

    public item(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

Here is activity xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.mysecondapp.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is content xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.example.mysecondapp.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="INSERT"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight="2" />
            <Button
                android:text="ADD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_text_view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What's wrong with the code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to say could you please explain a bit more

Comment: Recycler View just only show the first item of it's data set.Remaining items are not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
i have changed layout_height of LinearLayout to wrap_content

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_text_view"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set the height of the recycler item to match parent which means that the first item of your recycler view is taking the full screen. If you scroll you will find the other items at the bottom.

To fix this

In item.xml use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Instead of

```
  <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```